# How to test if a match exists in a string if the match can be a single string or a tuple of strings?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to do straight string matches from text files. Sometimes a match means a string contains multiple target strings. Currently I have code that looks like

```
interesting_matches = [
    "sys/bootdisk.py",
    " engine stalled for ",
    " changed to stalled)",
    "DSR failure",
    "Detected IDI failure",
    "idi_shallow_verify_failure",
    "Malformed block history",
    "Out of order sequence message on",
    "Port reset timeout of",
    "gmp_info",
    "test_thread",
    " panic @ time ",
    ": *** FAILED ASSERTION",
    "filesystem full",]

    for match in interesting_matches:
        # Iterate through simple matches.
        if match in line:
            processed_line_data = self._process_line(
                match,
                line,
                line_datetime,
                line_num,
                current_version)

    if "kern_sig" in line and "pid" in line:
        processed_line_data = self._process_line(
            ("kern_sig", "pid"),
            line,
            line_datetime,
            line_num,
            current_version)

    if "vfs_export" in line and "ignoring" in line:
        processed_line_data = self._process_line(
            ("vfs_export", "ignoring"),
            line,
            line_datetime,
            line_num,
            current_version)

    if "job_d" in line and
        "State transition from state " in line and
        " took longer than " in line:
        processed_line_data = self._process_line(
            (
                "job_d",
                "state transition from state",
                " took longer than "),
            line,
            line_datetime,
            line_num,
            current_version)

    if processed_line_data is not None:
        return_list.append(processed_line_data)
```

What I would love to do is something similar to

```
interesting_matches = [
        "sys/bootdisk.py",
        " engine stalled for ",
        " changed to stalled)",
        "DSR failure",
        "Detected IDI failure",
        "idi_shallow_verify_failure",
        "Malformed block history",
        "Out of order sequence message on",
        "Port reset timeout of",
        "gmp_info",
        "test_thread",
        " panic @ time ",
        ": *** FAILED ASSERTION",
        "filesystem full",
        ("kern_sig", "pid"),
        ("vfs_export", "ignoring"),
        ("job_d", "State transition from state", " took longer than "),]

for matches in interesting_matches
     if any(match in line for match in matches):
           processed_line_data = self._process_line(
               match,
               line,
               line_datetime,
               line_num,
               current_version)
```

But the mixing of tuples and strings causes a value error stating that you can't compare strings and tuples.

How can I write a single comparison if I want to have single and multiple strings to check for?

**EDIT:**

Here's working code based on Sean's answer

```
interesting_matches = [
    ("sys/bootdisk.py",),
    (" engine stalled for ",),
    (" changed to stalled)",),
    ("DSR failure",),
    ("Detected IDI failure",),
    ("idi_shallow_verify_failure",),
    ("Malformed block history",),
    ("Out of order sequence message on",),
    ("Port reset timeout of",),
    ("gmp_info",),
    ("test_thread",),
    (" panic @ time ",),
    (": *** FAILED ASSERTION",),
    ("filesystem full",),
    ("kern_sig", "pid"),
    ("vfs_export", "ignoring"),
    ("job_d", "State transition from state", " took longer than "),]

for matches in interesting_matches:
    if all(match in "test_thread" for match in matches):
        print(matches)
```

Comment: The term 'signature' means something specific in Python, and you might confuse people by using it.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/

Comment: Have any suggestions for a new term?

Comment: substring would be better

Comment: Would a set be better for `interesting_matches`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very doable. Try this: For the single-substring signatures, wrap them in a tuple anyway. Now your list is homogeneous and your problem becomes a lot simpler. For each signature tuple,  check to see if all substrings in the signature are also in the line.

Comment: `type(("sys/bootdisk.py"))` returns `str`

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins A tuple with 1 element needs a trailing comma.

Comment: @FMc That's a fun little gotcha. =P